# Google Analytics tracking on a single page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a landing page for an app that simply points to the google play store.

http://www.bryantmakesprograms.com/scanables/

The page has the following code at the top:

```
<script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'MY_SITE_CODE', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

When i look at my analytics account, I've had 4 page views over the course of 2 days.

I paid a person on fiverr to direct traffic to the landing page. They are directing users to a google shortened url, and they gave me this url to track the traffic:

https://goo.gl/#analytics/goo.gl/E2B937/all_time

That url claims I've gotten 90 views today alone.

Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 2):

**Without knowing the full details, it's tough to say, but it's possible you're getting scammed.**

**First, It looks like the URL was created just a few hours ago.** If you're not looking at Real Time results, then Google Analytics will not count pageviews for a little bit (48 hours if I remember correctly). Check under `Real Time` > `Overview`

Next, I would check to make sure your tracking code is measuring visitors. To do that, load your site and then check Google Analytics Real Time to see if the code is registering you as a user. Unless you have filtered your IP address to remove your visits from being counted in Analytics.

If your code is installed correctly, then it's possible the person is sending automated or farmed clicks. Thus the page isn't being loaded fully, and Google Analytics isn't registering a page view.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking as well, but I wasnt entirely sure how he could pull it off. If the page isn't loading fully, however, that would do the trick. I'll keep an eye on analytics data over the course of the next couple days though just to be sure :) Thanks!